# Outlook Web Addin - Popup for custom calculation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsto, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a requirement of creating an Outlook addin for some time calculations. Actual requirements are -

- Adding a button in the ribbon that will open a popup page
- This page will read its html and data from the server
- This will not be reading any mail data and not dependent on any other actions except than opened by clicking the button
- This has to work with Outlook 2007 to O365

Using Visual Studio 2015, I have looked at VSTO but they don't have html pages that can read the html from server. I have also looked at Outlook WebAddin - Module extension but that works with only Outlook 2016 and above.

Can anyone please suggest me what is the right approach to my requirement. I can provide more clarification on the requirement if asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Outlook Web Addin platform for Outlook 2013 and above to open a dialog on your button click and display html content in it. Refer the documentation here: https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted

This is the link to display dialog documentation:
https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.ui.html#displayDialogAsync

This will allow your addin to work on both Outlook desktop and Outlook Web. Let us know if this was helpful.

If Outlook 2007 is a must then web addins will not be supported so a com-addin is your only option.

Comment: Is this an official account? You shouldn't be editing in tags to questions indiscriminately; it changes the meaning.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT please can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393819/how-to-properly-handle-multiple-taskpanes-in-office-react-addin